# How to exit the whole try block when I encounter an error inside a function that I created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, return, try-catch

```
try {
    const skills = []
    
    req.body.skills.forEach(async (element) => {
        const skill = await Skill.findOne({name : element.skill})

        if (!skill) {
            return res.status(400).send('Skill : '+element.skill+' is not present')
        }

        skills.push(
            {
                skill : skill._id,
                skillname : skill.name
            }
        )
    })

    if (!await User.findOne(req.params)) {
        return res.status(400).send('The username : '+req.params.username+' doesnot exist')
    }

    console.log(skills);

    res.status(200).send(req.body)

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

In this I am getting the error, when the skill is not there in the database , as :

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\Teamin\teaminbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\Teamin\teaminbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (D:\Teamin\teaminbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\Teamin\teaminbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at D:\Teamin\teaminbackend\router\user.js:48:25
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
```

code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

SO I want to know how to exit the whole try block when I encounter an error inside a function that I created(the return statement only breaks out of the function I created and not the whole try block because of which it tries to run the code

```
res.send(req.body)
```

which results into the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the MDN Docs of [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> Note: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
> throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
> is the wrong tool.
>
> Early termination may be accomplished with:
>
> - A simple for loop
> - A for...of / for...in loops Array.prototype.every()
> - Array.prototype.some()
> - Array.prototype.find()
> - Array.prototype.findIndex()
>
> Array methods: every(), some(), find(), and findIndex() test the array elements with a predicate returning a truthy value to determine if further iteration is required.

So you need to use a `for` loop for control flow instead of [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
try {
    const skills = []
    
    for (const element of req.body.skills) {
    
        const skill = await Skill.findOne({name : element.skill})

        if (!skill) {
            return res.status(400).send('Skill : '+element.skill+' is not present')
        }

        skills.push(
            {
                skill : skill._id,
                skillname : skill.name
            }
        )
    }

    if (!await User.findOne(req.params)) {
        return res.status(400).send('The username : '+req.params.username+' doesnot exist')
    }

    console.log(skills);

    res.status(200).send(req.body)

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

This way, the `return` statement makes the surrounding function return (not the [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback which has no effect at all).

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
try {
    const skills = []
    
    req.body.skills.forEach(async (element) => {
        const skill = await Skill.findOne({name : element.skill})

        if (!skill) {
            throw { status: 400, message: 'Skill :'+element.skill+'is not present' };
        }

        skills.push(
            {
                skill : skill._id,
                skillname : skill.name
            }
        )
    })

    if (!await User.findOne(req.params)) {
        throw { status: 400, message: 'The username : '+req.params.username+' doesnot exist' };
    }

    console.log(skills);

    res.status(200).send(req.body)

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(error.status).send(error.message);
}
```

Comment: By using this I am getting error like :
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:21752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`